# How do you get Music Kits?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Yesterday (10/10/14), Valve released Music Kits, as outlined in the [Counter-Strike Global Offensive blog](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2014/10/10432/). According to the blog, they can be received by "offers in-game" or purchased from the market.

> Want a music kit? They’re available as offers in game, or you can pick one up now through the Steam market.

What exactly do they mean by "offers in-game", and how do you actually get one (apart from buying them from the market?
*I couldn't find a way to get them from cases or any usual key-and-crate method. Neither can I find them being sold in the "store".*

NB: The store is that bar above the blog with the cases and such. As per current, it only sells keys and contain info about the crates. Apart from that, you can't buy the Music Kits directly as a microtransation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Music kits can't be dropped, but only offers(looks like crates and works in the same way.)

[You can buy Music kits on the steam market from other users,](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=music&category_730_ItemSet[]=any&category_730_TournamentTeam[]=any&category_730_Weapon[]=any&appid=730) or you just have to get lucky and drop the offer in game to got the chance to buy a 6.99$ usd coupon; giving you the music kit.

Once you have drop the offer, and use it, you'll see the coupon, and will be able to buy the music [image]

Comment: Do you have any credible source? (Like a screenshot of someone getting it through the random drop system?)

Comment: @aytimothy answer fixed.

Comment: Just wondering: Are those coupons tradable (even an item)? Or instantly used up; the offer goes straight into your CS:GO screen, as shown in your screenshot?

Comment: I fixed again, i miss understood how the drop is done. Everyting should be ok now.

Comment: So the 'offer' is an item; consumable that you use that will put that *thing* in the "shop" bar?

Comment: You drop the 'offer', you use it, and you can buy the music

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but this coupon thing is going on with some stickers too. I got a coupon just like that, but only for a sticker. I couldn't trade or sell the coupon, it became mine automatically as it dropped. So I assume you can not trade the coupon things. Once you get a coupon you are the only one who can use it.